# Quartz Scheduler Getting Shut Down Again & Again

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

We have a Spring 4 application which uses Quartz 2.2.0 scheduler. Since recently, Quartz schedular shut down suddenly during the execution and recover again in few minutes. We can not see exception or any root cause with the logs even. Can anyone please support on,

1. Is there anyway to get/configure more logs for the Quartz
2. What can be the possible root causes for such scenarios

Following is a sample log for such failures

[image]